# Redis with multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nosql, redis

I'm trying to use redis with multidimensional array by using HMSET.
My array looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [t] => Hello
    [a] => This
    [c] => key
    [b] => 23
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => some value
            [more] => value
        )

)
```

Is there any way I can store data in this format in the redis using predis library.

Comment: my Question was to add multidimensional array by using hash, if we serialise and store then it will be string, and we wont be able to sort or query into it.

Comment: That naturally is not possible. In your case you could serialze  the `data` key only, and keep the rest as-is - if it helps. If not, you need to further on normalize the array structure. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Redis is able to store [strings](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) and PHP is able to serialize (multidimensional) array to strings.

The [`serialize` function](http://php.net/serialize) in the example can be used for that exact job, but is only exemplary, you can use any serialization method that serializes your data into a (binary) string.

For example you can make use of JSON ([`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)), [XML](http://php.net/refs.xml) or in some cases just [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) might be fitting.

```
$string = serialize(Array
(
    [t] => Hello
    [a] => This
    [c] => key
    [b] => 23
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => some value
            [more] => value
        )

));

$cmdSet = $redis->createCommand('set');
$cmdSet->setArgumentsArray(array('thisispredisdoingredis', $string));
```

Comment: does not this serialize and unserialize decrease performance?

Comment: Redis doesn't speak PHP so you need to send it in a format you can store in Redis. Two contesters would be to serialize as a PHP object (results in a PHP specific string, see answer) or as JSON (also a string). Serialization always takes time but it's probably negligible, when important (and to be sure), do some tests.

Answer (score 4):

A better way to do this is by `json_encode` your array in PHP and store it as *set* in Redis

```
$string = json_encode(Array
(
    [t] => Hello
    [a] => This
    [c] => key
    [b] => 23
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => some value
            [more] => value
        )   
));
```